# Use both Realm Swift and Realm Objective-C in same project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I'm trying to use both [Realm Swift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest) and [Realm Objective-C](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest) in same project.

I'm working on a project written in Objective-C, and I'm migrating it to Swift part by part. My existing Realm models are written in Objective-C using Realm Objective-C. I want to make new models written in Swift using Realm Swift. I know I can use Swift with Realm Objective-C, but I don't want to. My plan is that at the end of the migration from Objective-C to Swift, I'll delete Realm Objective-C and use Realm Swift only.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not supported. To quote from the first paragraph of the [Realm Swift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/):

> If you’re looking to use Realm from Objective‑C, or from mixed Objective‑C & Swift apps, please see Realm Objective‑C instead. The Realm Objective‑C and Realm Swift APIs are not interoperable and using them together is not supported.

I'd suggest using Realm Objective-C from Swift as you migrate your codebase to Swift, and then switching over to Realm Swift once your model classes are no longer accessed from Objective-C.